# Is there a better way of finding solution than using nested loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, nested-loops, gpu.js

I am looking to speed up the process of testing all the combinations based on the nested loops in the piece of code included.

I am currently stuck with JavaScript and NodeJS on Windows 10.

Is there a way to compute this using GPU rather than CPU?

```
var simulations = 0;
for (let i = 10; i <= 20; i++) {
    breakStepThree = i;
    for (let i = 8; i <= 12; i++) {
        historyLevelThree = i;
        for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i += 5) {
            rateLevelThree = i;
            for (let i = 10; i <= 16; i++) {
                breakStepTwo = i;
                for (let i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
                    historyLevelTwo = i;
                    for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i += 5) {
                        rateLevelTwo = i;
                        for (let i = 10; i <= 14; i++) {
                            breakStepOne = i;
                            for (let i = 4; i <= 8; i++) {
                                historyLevelOne = i;
                                for (let i = 0; i <= 40; i += 5) {
                                    rateLevelOne = i;
                                    simulations++;
                                    console.log('testing combination '
                                        + rateLevelOne + ' ' + historyLevelOne + ' ' + breakStepOne + ' '
                                        + rateLevelTwo + ' ' + historyLevelTwo + ' ' + breakStepTwo + ' '
                                        + rateLevelThree + ' ' + historyLevelThree + ' ' + breakStepThree
                                    );
                                    console.log('performing test no ' + simulations);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of worker threads to the best of my ability.

```
const {
    Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

const os = require('os');

if (isMainThread) {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    const workers = [];

    // const numberOfThreads = 1;
    const numberOfThreads = os.cpus().length;

    let completed = 0;

    let minBreakStep = 10;
    let maxBreakStep = 20;
    let minMaxElements = [];

    for (let i = minBreakStep; i <= maxBreakStep; i++) {
        minMaxElements.push(i);
    }

    const numberOfElements = minMaxElements.length;

    const numElementsPerThread = Math.ceil(numberOfElements / numberOfThreads);

    let workerIndex = 0;

    let allSimulations = 0;

    for (let i = minBreakStep; i <= maxBreakStep; i += numElementsPerThread) {
        let workerStart = i;
        let workerEnd = i + numElementsPerThread - 1;
        if (workerEnd > maxBreakStep) {
            workerEnd = maxBreakStep
        }

        const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
            workerData: {
                workerIndex,
                workerStart,
                workerEnd,
            }
        });

        worker.on('message', (message) => {
            if (message.completed) {
                completed++;
                console.log('worker ' + message.workerIndex + ' completed ' + message.simulations + ' simulations.');
                allSimulations += message.simulations;
            }
            if (completed === workers.length) {
                console.log('Completed all ' + allSimulations + ' done!');
                const endTime = Date.now();
                const elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
                console.log(elapsedTime + ' second(s) to complete');
            }
        });
        workerIndex++;
        workers.push(worker);
    }

} else {

    let workerIndex = workerData.workerIndex;
    let workerStart = workerData.workerStart;
    let workerEnd = workerData.workerEnd;

    let simulations = 0;

    for (let i = workerStart; i <= workerEnd; i++) {
        breakStepThree = i;
        for (let i = 8; i <= 12; i++) {
            historyLevelThree = i;
            for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i += 5) {
                rateLevelThree = i;
                for (let i = 10; i <= 16; i++) {
                    breakStepTwo = i;
                    for (let i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
                        historyLevelTwo = i;
                        for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i += 5) {
                            rateLevelTwo = i;
                            for (let i = 10; i <= 14; i++) {
                                breakStepOne = i;
                                for (let i = 4; i <= 8; i++) {
                                    historyLevelOne = i;
                                    for (let i = 0; i <= 40; i += 5) {
                                        rateLevelOne = i;
                                        simulations++;
                                        // console.log('testing combination '
                                        //     + rateLevelOne + ' ' + historyLevelOne + ' ' + breakStepOne + ' '
                                        //     + rateLevelTwo + ' ' + historyLevelTwo + ' ' + breakStepTwo + ' '
                                        //     + rateLevelThree + ' ' + historyLevelThree + ' ' + breakStepThree
                                        // );
                                        // console.log('performing test no ' + simulations);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('testing completed');
    parentPort.postMessage({
        completed: true,
        workerIndex: workerIndex,
        simulations: simulations,
    });
}
```

Comment: If you actually have to do such an astronomical number of combinations, how exactly you arrange the code probably doesn't matter at all. What you posted means that whatever has to be done, is going to be done almost 20 million times.

Comment: There's going to be a large number of combinations here. Since every combination will need to be run, you could split the tasks up into several async threads. The more threads/memory your server has the faster this can be finished

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, I'm unaware of any easy to use the GPU. Depending on the nature of the work being done to test each combination and the characteristics of your host system, you can use the built-in [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and/or [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) modules to spread out the work. The `worker_threads` module creates threads within a process. The `cluster` module creates separate processes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the worker threads direction, it definitely speeds up the computation.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of worker threads to the best of my ability.

```
const {
    Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

const os = require('os');

if (isMainThread) {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    const workers = [];

    // const numberOfThreads = 1;
    const numberOfThreads = os.cpus().length;

    let completed = 0;

    let minBreakStep = 10;
    let maxBreakStep = 20;
    let minMaxElements = [];

    for (let i = minBreakStep; i <= maxBreakStep; i++) {
        minMaxElements.push(i);
    }

    const numberOfElements = minMaxElements.length;

    const numElementsPerThread = Math.ceil(numberOfElements / numberOfThreads);

    let workerIndex = 0;

    let allSimulations = 0;

    for (let i = minBreakStep; i <= maxBreakStep; i += numElementsPerThread) {
        let workerStart = i;
        let workerEnd = i + numElementsPerThread - 1;
        if (workerEnd > maxBreakStep) {
            workerEnd = maxBreakStep
        }

        const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
            workerData: {
                workerIndex,
                workerStart,
                workerEnd,
            }
        });

        worker.on('message', (message) => {
            if (message.completed) {
                completed++;
                console.log('worker ' + message.workerIndex + ' completed ' + message.simulations + ' simulations.');
                allSimulations += message.simulations;
            }
            if (completed === workers.length) {
                console.log('Completed all ' + allSimulations + ' done!');
                const endTime = Date.now();
                const elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
                console.log(elapsedTime + ' second(s) to complete');
            }
        });
        workerIndex++;
        workers.push(worker);
    }

} else {

    let workerIndex = workerData.workerIndex;
    let workerStart = workerData.workerStart;
    let workerEnd = workerData.workerEnd;

    let simulations = 0;

    for (let i = workerStart; i <= workerEnd; i++) {
        breakStepThree = i;
        for (let i = 8; i <= 12; i++) {
            historyLevelThree = i;
            for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i += 5) {
                rateLevelThree = i;
                for (let i = 10; i <= 16; i++) {
                    breakStepTwo = i;
                    for (let i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
                        historyLevelTwo = i;
                        for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i += 5) {
                            rateLevelTwo = i;
                            for (let i = 10; i <= 14; i++) {
                                breakStepOne = i;
                                for (let i = 4; i <= 8; i++) {
                                    historyLevelOne = i;
                                    for (let i = 0; i <= 40; i += 5) {
                                        rateLevelOne = i;
                                        simulations++;
                                        // console.log('testing combination '
                                        //     + rateLevelOne + ' ' + historyLevelOne + ' ' + breakStepOne + ' '
                                        //     + rateLevelTwo + ' ' + historyLevelTwo + ' ' + breakStepTwo + ' '
                                        //     + rateLevelThree + ' ' + historyLevelThree + ' ' + breakStepThree
                                        // );
                                        // console.log('performing test no ' + simulations);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('testing completed');
    parentPort.postMessage({
        completed: true,
        workerIndex: workerIndex,
        simulations: simulations,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use CUDA bindings to perform calculations on GPU. Maybe in this case it would be better to interface a C program and import/export the experimental design and results. https://github.com/kashif/node-cuda / https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuda-node-js

Additionally I would get rid of all these nested loops with something like below. For performance sake maybe get rid of the slicing, and check the parameters as the few lines below are just to get the idea across.

```
class ExperimentGenerator{

  let pointer = 0;
  const initialParams = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  let params = [...initialParams]
  const maxValue = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]

  nextExperiment = () =>{
     if(params[pointer] >= maxValue[pointer]){
         pointer++;
         //Reset all other parameters
         params = [initialParams.slice(0,pointer),params[pointer],initialParams.slice(pointer)];
     }
     params[pointer]++;
     return params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but C is beyond my capabilities at this moment.
Furthermore, I tried to implement your experiment generator (great name) but unfortunately, I failed.